# $.cookie can not remove the cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
to manage my cookies.

when I call `$.removeCookie('the_cookie')`,it returns true, but when I do `$.cookie('the_cookie')`, the value is still there.

Anyone knows what might have gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you refresh the page between removing and trying to access the cookie?

Comment: Maybe it's an [evercookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evercookie), you just did'nt know it ?

Answer (score 1):

[Check this out!](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/09/jquery-cookies-getsetdelete-plugin.html)

basically the link gives a way to delete the cookie by setting its time to a negative time, so when it expires the cookie is gone. ( in Javascript ) and here is a way to do it in Jquery style.

```
//setting the cookie
$.cookie({'myCookie':'myValue'});

// Get a cookie
$.cookie('myCookie');

// Delete a cookie
$.cookie('myCookie', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the jquery-cookie plugin quite problematic in a number of occasions while using different browsers and versions of jquery. I have since decided to only use [these W3SCHOOLS cookie functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) which seem to work well and consistently across browsers. Do a setCookie(c_name,value,0) to unset a cookie with them.

Comment: W3C !== W3Schools, not only !== but also very, very, very far away. Many galaxies, universes and infinities away as it is not even affiliated with W3C.